# SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000 - Field 'rating_id' doesn't have a default value / When saving a child entity with one-to-one relation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities with a one-to-one bidirectional relation.

The parent entity:

```java
package com.pierre.inventorymanager.model;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Rating {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Product product;
    private Float rate;
    @Column(name = "review_left")
    private boolean reviewLeft;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "review_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Review review;

    public void setProduct(Product product) {

        Product oldProduct = this.product;

        if (Objects.equals(product, oldProduct))
            return;

        this.product = product;

        if (oldProduct != null)
            oldProduct.removeRating(this);

        if (product != null)
            product.addRating(this);
    }

    public void setRate(Float rate) {

        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public void setReviewLeft(boolean reviewLeft) {

        this.reviewLeft = reviewLeft;
    }

    public void setReview(Review review) {

        Review oldReview = this.review;

        if (Objects.equals(review, oldReview))
            return;

        this.review = review;

        if (oldReview != null)
            oldReview.setRating(null);

        if (review != null)
            review.setRating(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "Rating " + id + " : [productID = " + product.getId() + ", rate = " + rate +
               ", reviewLeft = " + reviewLeft + ", review = " + review + "]";
    }
}
```

The corresponding MySQL table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inventory.rating
(
    `id`          INT     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `product_id`  INT     NOT NULL,
    `review_id`   INT,
    `rate`        INT,
    `review_left` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The child entity:

```java
package com.pierre.inventorymanager.model;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Review {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "review", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Rating rating;
    private String title;
    private String body;

    public void setRating(Rating rating) {

        Rating oldRating = this.rating;

        if (Objects.equals(rating, oldRating))
            return;

        this.rating = rating;

        if (oldRating != null)
            oldRating.setReview(null);

        if (rating != null)
            rating.setReview(this);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {

        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {

        this.body = body;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "Review " + id + " : [ratingID = " + rating.getId() + ", title = " + title +
               ", body = " + body.substring(0, Math.min(body.length(), 10)) + "]";
    }
}
```

Its table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inventory.review
(
    `id`        INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `rating_id` INT         NOT NULL,
    `title`     VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `body`      TEXT        NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I'm retrieving the values of both entities through this form using Thymeleaf as template:

```html
<form class="user" action="#" th:action="@{/product/{id}/product_rated(id = ${product.id})}"
      th:object="${rating}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p>Rate Product:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-container col-sm-3">
            <input th:field="*{rate}" type="range" min="1" max="5" step="1" value="3"
                   class="slider" id="myRange"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
            <input th:field="*{reviewLeft}" type="checkbox"
                   class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck"
                   onchange="document.getElementById('inputTitle').disabled = !this.checked;
                   document.getElementById('inputBody').disabled = !this.checked;"/>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Leave Review</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input th:field="*{review.title}" type="text" disabled
                   class="form-control form-control-user"
                   id="inputTitle" placeholder="Title for your review"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <textarea th:field="*{review.body}" class="form-control rounded-0" rows="10"
                      id="inputBody" placeholder="Tell us what you think.." disabled>
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block col-sm-3">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller methods:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/product/{id}/rate_product")
public String rateProduct(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("rating", new Rating());
    model.addAttribute("product", service.getProductByID(id));
    return "rate_product";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/product/{id}/product_rated")
public String saveProductRating(@PathVariable("id") long id, @ModelAttribute("rating") Rating rating) {

    service.saveRating(rating, id);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

When trying to call this method in my Service, neither parent nor child get saved and the exception is thrown:

```java
public void saveRating(Rating rating, long id) {

    Product product = productRepository.getById(id);
    rating.setProduct(product);
    ratingRepository.save(rating);
}
```

```error
2021-03-21 12:33:47.507  WARN 5448 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2021-03-21 12:33:47.507 ERROR 5448 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'rating_id' doesn't have a default value
2021-03-21 12:33:47.531 ERROR 5448 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Field 'rating_id' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3806) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~
.
.
.
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.5-20210315.181825-80.jar:5.3.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5-20210315.181825-80.jar:5.3.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

At first I thought the problem was because I'm trying to save both entities at the same time when neither had any id in the tables, so I changed the code to:

```java
public void saveRating(Rating rating, long id) {

    Product product = productRepository.getById(id);
    rating.setProduct(product);
    Review review = rating.getReview();

    rating.setReview(null);
    ratingRepository.save(rating);

    review.setRating(rating);
    reviewRepository.save(review);
}
```

With the above code, saving the parent `Rating` works fine, the problem occurs when hibernate tries to save the child `Review`. I tried all `CascadeType`s on either and both entities and both `FetchType`s and nothing seems to work. I also tried `GenerationType.AUTO` and didn't work either. Dropping the database also didn't work.

`application.properties`:

```ini
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory?allowMultiQueries=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.separator=^;
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Changing ddl mode to `create` and `update` didn't yield any results.

**Note**

A `Rating` should be able to exist without a `Review` (a user rates the product without leaving a review) but a `Review` should always have a parent `Rating`. That's the intended behaviour I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you check if the `rating_id` value in the `Rating` table has any default value?

Comment: Yes there is, the value is saved in the `Rating` table but with no reference to the `Review` (corresponding `review_id` is null).

Comment: In saveRating (), you have setReview(null)

Comment: Yes it was an experiment to check whether the problem was saving the parent or the child. Seems it’s because of the child, the parent got saved this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I was wrong.

You don't need the rating_id because you are using review_id on the rating table for that purpose already.

So you can delete rating_id on the review table.

Comment: I want the `Review` to be optional so that the user may or may not leave a review after rating the product.

Comment: Yes that solved it, thanks for the answer.